# How to receive arrays parameters and return?

Tags: java, arrays

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] arr2 = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    System.out.println("same data are " + compareArray(arr1, arr2));
}

public static int compareArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                i = compareArray(arr1, arr2);
            }
        }
    }
    return compareArray(arr1, arr2);
}
```

this question is : receives two arrays as parameters and returns the number of matching data.
how do i output "same data are 2"?

Comment: Your parameters and return type declarations are correct. If its not working, that means the method body isn't correct.

Comment: And the thing which looks incorrect is that you are invoking `compareArray` recursively. Don't do that, just increment a counter when matches are found, and return the counter value at the end.

Comment: Why "same data are 2"?

Comment: @saka1029 that's my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a `Set` as well. Add the elements of `arr1` (or you can add elements of `arr2` according to your choice) into a `Set` and check whether the `Set` contains elements of `arr2`. If yes, increment the count.

```
public static int compareArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
     Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
     for(int i : arr1)
        set.add(i);
     int count = 0;
     for(int i : arr2) {
        if(set.contains(i))
            count++;
     }
     return count;
}
```

In your logic, just use a `count` variable as shown below:

```
public static int compareArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                 count++;
             }
         }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to call compareArray method recursively. Instead you can modify your method to:

```java
public static int compareArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```